# div hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, hover, jquery-hover

I am making a navigation bar but div hover using JQuery is not working. I am not sure where am I going wrong;
HTML code:

```
<div  id="Navigation_left_0"><a href="">click This</a>
    <ul id="navScroll_0" sizset="true">
        <li><a href="">abcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="">abxfdcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="">afgvbcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="">asfrbcd</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div  id="Navigation_left_1" ><a href="">click This</a>
    <ul id="navScroll_1" sizset="true">
        <li><a href="">abcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="">abxfdcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="">afgvbcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="">asfrbcd</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[id^="Navigation_left"]').hover(

    function() {
        alert("Hello");
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var idStr = id.split('_');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'grey');
        var idNum = parseInt(idStr[2]);
        var ulID = "#navScroll_" + idNum;
        $(ulID).css({
            'display': 'block',
            'height': '3em',
            'float': 'left',
            'padding-right': '2px'
        });
    }, function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var idStr = id.split('_');
        var idNum = parseInt(idStr[2]);
        $("#navScroll_" + idNum).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});​
```

CSS part:

```
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  height:50px;
  display:none;
}
ul li {
    height: 3em;
    float:left;
    padding-right:2px;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:33%;
   }
div {
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  width:"20%";
  height:"5%";
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  position:relative;
}
```

There are multiple divs but I have only put a piece of code which can help in understanding the code. The control is not going into div hover as even the alert is not coming up.one more thing I am using an ajax functionality in document.ready which is working fine. The mentioned jquery code is plugged in after the ajax call. I checked in both IE8 and chrome.

Comment: also try to use class selectors or id selectors for navigation elements. So you can use div's in your HTML for something else too.

Comment: I have updated the code to use id selectors for div but the code still not working for desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you hide the `ul` list so remove `display:none;` from ul css and then try

**[DEMO-1](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/Td566/3/)**

since you are hiding ul so there no content under div to hover on so try to add `min-height:10px;` to div

**[DEMO-2](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/Td566/4/)**

Comment: on Hover of div I am adding css to ul 'display':'block'. Anyway the problem is that div hover is not working. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I got your point from the attached demo. But why is that on hover of the div I am not able to display Ul using 'display': 'block',
so that the list is hidden on page load (putting display:none in css) and on div hover it shows the list and on mouseout again hide the list.

Comment: I have updated the code to add some text to div and used div id selector for hover functionality as suggested by Tim above

Comment: The code is working fine now. I had the parseInt wrong too and so the correct id was not getting selected. Thanks for your help. I will now plugin this chunk in my original code and see how is it working.

Answer (score 0):

Due to `ul` css is `display:none;` so it is not displaying any thing and hover is not working. Plese remove `display:none;` css from `ul`.

Comment: I want the list to be hidden on page load (putting display:none in css) and on div hover using 'display': 'block', it should show the list and on mouseout again hide the list.

Comment: I have updated the code to put some text in div. I missed this while posting the code here.

Comment: The code is working fine now. I had the parseInt wrong too and so the correct id was not getting selected. Thanks for your help.